# CATransform3DMakeRotation frame

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a custom view `MyView` (red) that contains one subview `MySubView` (blue). I want to rotate the subview around its center.

My problem is that when I setup the `MySubview` using autolayout, the rotation works fine:

[image] [image]

but when I set the frame of the subview (without autolayout) the rotation distorts the view:

[image]

In the `MySubview` class I expose a property that sets the rotation as follows

```
var rotateAngle: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        let measurement = Measurement(value: Double(rotateAngle), unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
        let radians = measurement.converted(to: UnitAngle.radians).value
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(radians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    }
}
```

In the `MyView`, the autolayout is set using

```
subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
    subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
    subview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
    subview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),

    ])
```

When I set it without using autolayout, I simply set the subview frame

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    subview.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 4), size: CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height / 2))
}
```

The reason I don't want to use autolayout is because in the real app, I have hundreds of view refreshed quite often which performs better without autolayout.

Here is a complete listing that

```
class RotateViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myView: MyView!
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        myView = MyView()
        view.addSubview(myView)

        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
            ])

    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged() {
        myView.subview.rotateAngle = Int(slider.value)
    }
}

class MySubView: UIView {

    var rotateAngle: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            let measurement = Measurement(value: Double(rotateAngle), unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
            let radians = measurement.converted(to: UnitAngle.radians).value
            layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(radians), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .blue

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        backgroundColor = .blue;
    }
}

class MyView: UIView {

    let useAutoLayout = false

    var subview = MySubView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(subview)
        backgroundColor = .red
        setupConsraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSubview(subview)
        backgroundColor = .red
        setupConsraints()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if useAutoLayout {
            return
        }
        subview.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 4), size: CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height / 2))
    }

    private func setupConsraints() {
        if !useAutoLayout {
            return
        }
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            subview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            subview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),

            ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This because of re-run of this

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if(once)
    {
        subview.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 4), size: CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height / 2))

        print(subview.frame)

        once = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in this particular case but won't work if the frame of the MyView changes. The root cause is that the setting the `transform` property of the `UIView` the frame becomes invalid: "If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored."

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [docs of UIView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame) I believe that the root cause is that the frame becomes invalid after setting the `transform` property to something else that identity:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So instead of using the `frame` of the rotated view, I can use its bounds to set it up:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    subview.bounds.size = CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height / 2)
    subview.center = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're constantly resetting the frame of the view, which is throwing off the `transform`. In `MyView` update `setupConsraints()` i.e.

```
private func setupConsraints() {
    if !useAutoLayout {
        subview.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 4), size: CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height / 2))
        return
    }
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        ...
        ])
}
```

and then you can delete the `layoutSubviews()` function altogether.

Comment: but `layoutSubviews` *is* the place where you are supposed to set the frames of your subviews: "You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly."